# IOS PayPal SDK: Request has failed with error: PAYEE_ACCOUNT_INVALID - Vendor account does not have a confirmed email. (400)

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, sandbox, credit-card

Got error when trying to do payment using Paypal with credit-card in ios swift 3

Note : [sandbox, PayPal iOS SDK 2.16.1][[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTbMe.png)

Comment: Does your seller account exist on PayPal and have a registered email address?

Comment: @mikep Thank for reply , Yes seller account exist on Paypal and has a register email address

Comment: @Reema have you found any solution?

Comment: @Reema have you found any solution, i have same issue in android.

Comment: @MukeshKumar I had the same problem with the android app. did you get any solution?

Comment: I also have same issue now . Any one got the solution?